# CAKeyframeAnimation - move along path and use easing

Tags: ios, uikit, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation, easing

Is it possible to use CAKeyframeAnimation to move something along a path and at the same time use some sort of easing so there is acceleration or deceleration?  I know there is timingFunctions and keyTimes, but I don't see how they would work if you are simply moving along a path.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like

```
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]
```

?

Or swift 5:

```
anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
```

Comment: I should have looked.  Only saw timingFunctions as a property on CAKeyframeAnimation.  Didn't think to look if there was a single property on CABAsicAnimation.  Thanks.

Comment: I looked and some of the docs explicitly say this value is ignored for keyframe animations. Those docs are wrong; this works.